# How can I remove a stuck screw that will still turn?

Tags: screws, woodworking, removal

I put a too short screw into the screw hole.  I thought this would sort things out.  It didn't.  Now I cannot get the screw out even though it will turn quite freely with a Phillips screwdriver.  Any ideas?  Could I superglue another similar sized screw to it, head to head?

Comment: Can you pull or pry on it while you turn it. This usually works for me. If you are screwing into metal and the hole is threaded and the threads are stripping, then this probably won't work though.

Comment: How much space do you have between the walls of the hole and the circumference of the screw head?

Comment: What about a magnetic screwdriver bit?

Answer (score 3):

I have found two methods that work for me:

1. Use plyers instead of screw driver
2. Use a paint scraper pressed underneath the screw head while you turn the screw with driver.  Between the additional friction, and the scraper blade, frequently the screw thread will start to catch, and allow it to back out.

Comment: another variation of method two is to slip the tip of an utility knife and gently pry up while spinning.  Use a light touch, perhaps followed by the aforementioned putty scraper.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a piece of ABC (Already Been Chewed) gum to pull the screw out, does it for me every time.